# How to add header to axios POST for nodemailer using Firebase function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios, nodemailer

I am trying to include nodemailer in a Firebase Cloud Function, and call it using Axios in a React app. The function is working using:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json"  https://us-central1-journeylife-dev.cloudfunctions.net/sendPulse -d '{"pulseUrl":"journeylife.typeform.com","pulseTitle":"test pulse"}'
```

When I try to call the function from my app with a POST request, it always times out.

The only difference I see between the cURL request and my axios request is the header. I cannot tell if I'm using the header incorrectly or if there is an additional step I need calling from the app.

Here is my function that contains the axios POST request:

```
sendPulse() {
        axios.post('https://us-central1-journeylife-dev.cloudfunctions.net/sendPulse', {
            pulseUrl: this.state.pulseUrl,
            pulseTitle: this.state.pulseTitle,
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
            }).then(function () {
                document.getElementById('sentPulse').style.display = 'block';
            })
    }
```

Here is the function (requirements and transporter not included):

```
exports.sendPulse = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    if (req.body.pulseUrl == null || req.body.pulseTitle == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // setup e-mail data, even with unicode symbols
    const mailOptions = {
        from: '"JourneyLIFE " <jonathan@gojourneylife.com>', // sender address (who sends)
        to: 'jonathan@kairosgarage.com', // list of receivers (who receives)
        subject: req.body.pulseTitle, // Subject line
        text: 'Hello world', // plaintext body
        html: '<b>Hello world </b><br> This is the first email sent with Nodemailer in Node.js', // html body
    };

    // send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }

        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        res.status(200).json('Pulse Sent')
    });
});
```

Comment: hey there! cloud functions need to return a promise, it looks yours it's not, the first I would check is to add a return statement on the transporter.sendMail

Comment: @andresmijares Added a return function to the console log, but I didn't get any different results

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a promise in order to avoid the time out...

```
  // send mail with defined transport object
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            return res.send(erro.toString());
        }

        console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        return res.status(200).json('Pulse Sent')
    });
```

That should be good enough

Comment: Not affecting anything. It is failing due to timeout, so I believe there is a problem before this point. Also, works when simply requesting via cURL. I added a couple console logs, and it appears I am not even reaching the sendMail function

Comment: another thing to add then... based on this I assume the function is breaking on the (req.body.pulseUrl == null || req.body.pulseTitle == null), you probably want to check if you are receiving the data you are expecting correctly

Comment: also consider it can return cors issues on the browser

Comment: Okay, it looks like there is no data being sent during the request. req.body is an empty object. Not sure what causes that, but looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The function needs to have cors (which I don't fully understand yet), but here is the implementation

```
exports.sendPulse = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
         //body of function
    })
});
```

Don't forget to require cors in top of the file and in package.json